# Haskell filling list with missing elements

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to write a function

```
fill::Int->Int->[(Int, Int, Int)]->[(Int, Int, Int)] 
fill width height board = ...
```

that "fills" the given board ( in a single (Int, Int, Int) triple on the board the first two Ints are coordinates, the third one is a value at that field ) with the missing ones (with third coordinate set to 0), e.g.:

```
let x = fill 3 3 [(1,2,2),(1,3,5),(3,2,3)]
```

should result in

```
x = [(1,1,0),(1,2,2),(1,3,5),(2,1,0),(2,2,0),(2,3,0),(3,1,0),(3,2,3),(3,3,0)].
```

Is there some nice function that could be used here, or is some complicated double recursion in order?

Comment: Can you assume the `board` is sorted?

Comment: @chi yes, it's sorted when I call the function

Comment: You could generate the board full of zeroes, and then walk along your input board and that zero board "in parallel", and fill in zeroes where needed. O(n^2) time complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct way may be (with ~O(n^2) cost)

```
fill :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)] 
fill a b defaults = [(x, y, maybe 0 id (search x y defaults)) | x <- [1..a], y <- [1..b]]
           where search _ _ [] = Nothing
                 search x y ((u,v,k):rs) | x == u && y == v = Just k
                                         | otherwise        = search x y rs
```

but I prefer split key/values like (with ~O(n log n) cost)

```
import Data.Map hiding (foldr)

-- using key/value
fill' :: Int -> Int -> [((Int, Int), Int)] -> [((Int, Int), Int)]
fill' a b defaults = assocs
                   $ foldr (\(k, v) m -> insertWith (+) k v m) empty
                   $ defaults ++ [((x,y),0) | x <- [1..a], y <- [1..b]]
```

example

```
main = do

    print $ fill 3 3 [(1,2,2),(1,3,5),(3,2,3)]
    print $ fill' 3 3 [((1,2),2),((1,3),5),((3,2),3)]
```

yours default values are 0, if not, you must replace `(+)` on `insertWith`. Can you think how?

Comment: The O(..) complexity bounds look a bit off -- you are producing a O(n^2)-long list as output, so you can't get lower than that.

Comment: @chi I add `~` to express an informal analysis, `n` is not an argument there but to me, is the length data (`n/2` defaults and `n/2` max data take `O(n^2)` and `O(n log n)` for each aproach). I think that is understandable and better than `O(a^4 b^4)` and `O(a^2 b^2 log ab)` :)

Comment: I am still puzzled. If I call e.g. `fill 10 10 defaults`, this produces a list having `10^2` cells, and for each of this you search defaults. Even assuming defaults is sparse and only ~10 cells long, we get to 10^3 total cost. I think the first case is O(n^3), at least.

Answer (score 6):

I'd start from e.g.

```
zeroBoard :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
zeroBoard width height = [ (x,y,0) | x <- [1..width], y <- [1..height] ]
```

Then we can use *single* recursion, as in:

```
fill::Int->Int->[(Int, Int, Int)]->[(Int, Int, Int)] 
fill width height board = go board $ zeroBoard width height
   where go []             zs                 = zs
         go (t@(x,y,z):bs) (t'@(x',y',z'):zs) =
                if ... 
                then t : go ...
                else t': go ...
```

You can even skip the zeros in `zeroBoard` and add 0 directly inside `go`.

Answer (score 2):

The array API is convenient here and gives you the right asymptotics as well.

```
import Data.Array

fill :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
fill width height board =
  map (\((x, y), v) -> (x, y, v)) . assocs $
    listArray ((1,1),(width,height)) (repeat 0)
      // map (\(x, y, v) -> ((x, y), v)) board
```

Comment: I would even be tempted to change the interface to `fill` for this example to cut out the mapping noise and show just how close a fit `Array` really is here.

Comment: (Also consider using `accumArray`; e.g. `fill w h b = assocs $ accumArray (\def actual -> actual) 0 ((1, 1), (w, h)) b`.)